# My processor is not detected intel core 2 duo

Tags: 10.10, intel, multi-core

My processor is not detected intel core 2 duo

When I type

> $uname -m -p

I get this

> i686 unknown

I have Ubuntu 10.10 netbook remix

but the cat /proc/cpuinfo gives right identification of two processors as below

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 15
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU         T5600  @ 1.83GHz
stepping    : 6
cpu MHz     : 1826.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat     pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm dts tpr_shadow
bogomips    : 3657.99
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 15
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU         T5600  @ 1.83GHz
stepping    : 6
cpu MHz     : 1826.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat     pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm dts tpr_shadow
bogomips    : 3657.53
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

The problem is with programs that uses more than one core like virtualbox and bitcoin which refuses to use more than one core

Is there anythign wrong or anything that I can do?

My installation is from a live usb iso on a USB

Answer (score 6):

As fas as I know everything is perfectly OK in your system. I have tried a couple of systems (my U2300 laptop, a Core2 server and a Pentium 4 server) and uname returns unknown in all, but all correctly identified in /proc/cpuinfo and all use full cores.

If you want VirtualBox to use more than one core you will need to give the virtual machine access to those cores in System->Processor tab in the virtual machine configuration screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

uname does not detect what kind of processor you have; it simply prints what target your kernel was built for.  The i686 target means a 32 bit kernel that runs on intel 686 and higher compatible processors.